# Receiving parameter in API method in Blazor Server project from GetFromJsonAsync call in Blazor WebAssembly Client project

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a Controller in my Blazor Server project and I am calling it from a razor page in the client project passing a parameter, eg

in razor page

```
var FlatData = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<TreeItem>>("TreeItem?Id=3FD09A3");
```

in server Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<TreeItem> Get(string tag)
{

    IEnumerable<TreeItem> treeItems =  Enumerable.Range(1, 11).Select(index => new TreeItem
    {
        ...
    })
    .ToArray();
    return treeItems;
}
```

TreeItem is a class defined in my Shared project.

I get into my Controller method OK and can return data OK, but I do not get the parameter to refine the data.  How do I get my parameter data from "TreeItem?Id=3FD09A3".  My "tag" parameter on my Get method is always null.  How can I get my parameter data?

Answer (score 1):

You have to match on name, case-sensitive:

```
[HttpGet]
//public IEnumerable<TreeItem> Get(string tag)
public IEnumerable<TreeItem> Get(string Id)   // because ?Id=3FD09A3
```

Comment: Thanks!  I Just what I needed to know.  I could have gone a long time and not thought of that.  You can see I am new to web programming.

Comment: @Henk is right. You'll have to match your parameter name inside method with querystring paramer including case-sensitive. For example - if you are passing "?tag=3FD09A3" in querystring, then method parameter must be "Get(string tag)". Then model binding will work only. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define the tag (string tag) in the routing.
In client:

```
var FlatData = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<TreeItem>>("TreeItem/3FD09A3");
```

And in the Controller:

```
[HttpGet/{tag}]
public IEnumerable<TreeItem> Get(string tag)
{
....
}
```